# NoMethodError for child object in nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create two objects from one nested form in Rails, `recipe` which `has_many :ingredients`.

When I submit the form, Rails returns an error:

```
undefined method `ingredient' for #<Ingredient id: nil, ing: "a", amount: "a", recipe_id: nil> Did you mean? increment
```

Specifically pointing out the error in my create action:

```
@recipe = Recipe.new(recipe_params)
 #   @recipe.user_id = session[:user_id]
    @recipe.save

    redirect_to recipe_path(@recipe)
end
```

I suspect my problem is in model associations.

Full trace:

```
Started POST "/recipes" for ::1 at 2016-12-19 13:53:06 -0600
Processing by RecipesController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"wmdURAmdmdHrbrW3+0z5MvEIOs7hY5QBfzKG/L1PSgFKJPRHbFQlGMpBYeIwYdnRxPprsEKk1HT7qQNbSOo42Q==", 
    "recipe"=>{"name"=>"adsfadsfa", 
        "steps"=>"a", 
        "ingredients_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"ing"=>"a", "amount"=>"a"}}}, 
        "commit"=>"Add"}
ActionController::Parameters {"name"=>"adsfadsfa", 
    "steps"=>"a", 
    "ingredients_attributes"=>
        <ActionController::Parameters 
            {"0"=><ActionController::Parameters 
                {"ing"=>"a", "amount"=>"a"} permitted: true>} permitted: true>} permitted: true>
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
(0.1ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 47ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)

app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb:13:in `create'
Rendering /Users/JCamp1991/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout
Rendering /Users/JCamp1991/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
Rendered /Users/JCamp1991/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (11.0ms)
Rendering /Users/JCamp1991/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
Rendered /Users/JCamp1991/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (5.6ms)
Rendering /Users/JCamp1991/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
Rendered /Users/JCamp1991/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (3.6ms)
Rendered /Users/JCamp1991/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (153.7ms)
Rendering /Users/JCamp1991/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/web-console-3.1.1/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb
Rendered /Users/JCamp1991/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/web-console-3.1.1/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (1.0ms)
Rendering /Users/JCamp1991/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/web-console-3.1.1/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript
Rendering /Users/JCamp1991/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/web-console-3.1.1/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string
Rendered /Users/JCamp1991/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/web-console-3.1.1/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.9ms)
Rendering /Users/JCamp1991/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/web-console-3.1.1/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string
Rendered /Users/JCamp1991/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/web-console-3.1.1/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (1.0ms)
Rendering /Users/JCamp1991/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/web-console-3.1.1/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string
Rendered /Users/JCamp1991/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/web-console-3.1.1/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (1.0ms)
Rendered /Users/JCamp1991/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/web-console-3.1.1/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (116.1ms)
Rendering /Users/JCamp1991/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/web-console-3.1.1/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript
Rendered /Users/JCamp1991/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/web-console-3.1.1/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.9ms)
Rendered /Users/JCamp1991/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/web-console-3.1.1/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (229.6ms)
```

recipes_controller.rb:

```
...
    def create
      @recipe = Recipe.new(recipe_params)
      @recipe.user_id = session[:user_id]
      @recipe.save

      redirect_to recipe_path(@recipe)
    end

...

    def recipe_params
      params.require(:recipe).permit(:name, :steps, ingredients_attributes: [:ing, :amount])
    end
```

Models:

```
class Ingredient < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :recipe
...
end

class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  has_many :ingredients
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients
  validates_associated :ingredients
  ...
end
```

New recipe form:

```
<%= form_for @recipe do |f| %>
<h1>
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %><br>
</h1>
<h1>
    <%= f.label :steps %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :steps %><br>
</h1>
<%= f.fields_for :ingredients do |p| %>
    <h1>
        <%= p.label :ing %><br>
        <%= p.text_area :ing %><br>
    </h1>
    <h1>
        <%= p.label :amount %><br>
        <%= p.text_area :amount %><br>
    </h1>
<% end %>
<%= f.submit "Add" %><br>
```

Included in routes.rb:

```
resources :users do
    resources :recipes
end
resources :recipes do
    resources :ingredients
end
```

Github Repo for entire project:

https://github.com/jlcampbell1991/recipe-box

Comment: Could you please add `p recipe_params` one line before the error, and show us the output?

Comment: Absolutely. Done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Ingredient` model probably shouldn't have an `ingredient` attribute. What about `name`?

It also doesn't seem to be consistent between migrations

`t.string :ing`

and Model :

`validates :ingredient, presence: true`

Comment: Yes, that is moving things along!  Now I am getting this error:

Comment: `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"recipes", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]`

Comment: In other words, the controller won't save a `recipe` because its `ingredients` need a `recipe_id` which doesn't exist until `recipe` is saved

Comment: I needed to alter my ingredient model to `belongs_to :recipe, optional: true` as per:  http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/15/rails-5-makes-belong-to-association-required-by-default.html